# Keras customizing train_step when using a custom optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to change what happens in train_step when using a custom optimizer but I get this error message when trying to compile the model:

> raise ValueError('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', identifier) ValueError: ('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', <**main**.Optimizer_quazi_Newton object at 0x0000019CFCC2EF60>)

The problem I'm having is that I want to selectively be able to feed the same data during training depending on what happens in the optimizer. My optimizer has a variable which basically say "I want the same data again" and I want to modify the fit function so that when the optimizer needs it I can feed it the same data instead of going to the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I was using different API's for my optimizer and my model, one was using keras, the other was using tensorflow.keras. If anyone runs into similar issues this might be the problem.